# Bootstrap table word wrap is not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have problem with a bootstrap table. The bootstrap table with this style works fine for wide screens but when I tried to see this tablet PC all the columns are overlapping on each other. Please help me out.

```css
.table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
               <tr>
           <th>Cbee ID</th>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
             <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Email</th>
           <th>Facebook ID</th>
           <th>LinkedIn ID</th>      
           <th>Owner Beevites</th>
           <th>Attendee Beevites</th>
            <th>Device ID</th>
   </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                  <td>9818c9b8d07c1bb507a05c387d3b3d743725ad81cb93f1858d5143ccd1624bdf</td>
                </tr>                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the same code i have used before...but still i have the same prob

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
 <div class="table-responsive">              
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```